# Perform UI operations before application goes into background

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I would like to perform some UI Operations before an application goes into the background ..

```
UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
```

just doesn't cut it .. 
I have a **MPMoviePlayerController** streaming an m3u8 file and i need to pause this video before the application goes into the background mainly because ..
If i do tap on the home button while the video is playing and come into the foreground again ..

The buffered stream of the video is lost and the video plays in a buggy manner and strangely this happens only on iPhone and not iPad ..
so i am hoping to work around this and pause the video **before** it goes into the background ..

Comment: Take a look at `UIApplicationWillEnterBackgroundNotification`

Comment: I dont think theres any such notification

Comment: You're right. Now I remember, it should be `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` if you're targeting iOS 4+

Comment: Thanks a lot .. you could post this as an answer so that i can accept it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` seems exactly what you're looking for.

ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this [Application Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a)

Or you can even perform task for a finite time after your application enter to background

[**Check out here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)